# Rotation problem

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, rotations

> With a 2D surface, we take $(2, 1)$ as the center point and consider a transformation with a rotation angle of $45^\circ$ so point $(3, 3)$ is transformed into point?

I'm really close to getting the answer! I've gotten $(-1/\sqrt2,3/\sqrt2)$ but the answer is $(2-1/\sqrt2, 3+1/\sqrt2)$. Please tell me what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

The displacement vector from $(2,1)$ to $(3,3)$ is $(1,2)$. Rotated counterclockwise by $45^\circ$, $(1,2)$ becomes
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\cos45^\circ&-\sin45^\circ\\
\sin45^\circ&\cos45^\circ
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\end{bmatrix}$$
$$=\frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{bmatrix}
1&-1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\end{bmatrix}=\frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{bmatrix}-1\\3\end{bmatrix}$$
Thus $(3,3)$ is transformed to $(2,1)+\frac1{\sqrt2}(-1,3)$ or $\left(2-\frac1{\sqrt2},1+\frac3{\sqrt2}\right)$.

Comment: Thank you, are those matrices? How can I learn more about this topic?

Comment: @JennYT They're rotation matrices. Look up Wikipedia for "rotation matrix".